# Iterating the JSON inside JSON in Angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Hi I am very new to the angular2 I want to iterate the JSON inside JSON objects
My JSON is shown below

```
{"items":[{"id":564,"sku":"MB570Z\/B","name":"Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter","attribute_set_id":4,"price":2800,"status":1,"visibility":4,"type_id":"simple","created_at":"2017-08-31 04:49:57","updated_at":"2017-08-31 05:06:31","weight":1,"extension_attributes":[],"product_links":[],"tier_prices":[],"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"description","value":"Every Mac with a Mini DisplayPort allows you to connect an external display or projector using an adapter. You can use an external display as your main workspace or to extend your desktop, or you can work in mirrored mode with a projector so you can view what your audience sees.\r\nUse the Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter to connect an advanced digital monitor, such as the 20- or 23-inch Apple Cinema Display, that includes a DVI connector. Review the documentation or check with the manufacturer of your monitor to make sure you're choosing the right adapter."},{"attribute_code":"short_description","value":"Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter"},{"attribute_code":"image","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"small_image","value":"\/a\/p\/apple_hdmi_to_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"thumbnail","value":"\/a\/p\/apple_hdmi_to_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"options_container","value":"container2"},{"attribute_code":"required_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"has_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"url_key","value":"mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter"},{"attribute_code":"msrp_display_actual_price_type","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"tax_class_id","value":"2"},{"attribute_code":"gift_message_available","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"is_featured","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source","value":"28"},{"attribute_code":"hsncode","value":"85444299"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source_after_minprice","value":"-1"}]},{"id":565,"sku":"MB571Z\/A","name":"Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter","attribute_set_id":4,"price":9400,"status":1,"visibility":4,"type_id":"simple","created_at":"2017-08-31 04:49:58","updated_at":"2017-08-31 05:06:31","weight":1,"extension_attributes":[],"product_links":[],"tier_prices":[],"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"description","value":"Every Mac with a Mini DisplayPort allows you to connect an external display or projector using an adaptor. You can use an external display as your main workspace or to extend your desktop, or you can work in mirrored mode with a projector so you can view what your audience sees.\nUse the Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adaptor to connect your Mac to a 30-inch display that includes a DVI connector, such as the 30-inch Apple Cinema Display HD, and enjoy the ultimate widescreen canvas with a resolution of 2560 by 1600 pixels."},{"attribute_code":"short_description","value":"Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter"},{"attribute_code":"image","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dual-link_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"small_image","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dual-link_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"thumbnail","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dual-link_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"options_container","value":"container2"},{"attribute_code":"required_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"has_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"url_key","value":"mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter"},{"attribute_code":"msrp_display_actual_price_type","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"tax_class_id","value":"2"},{"attribute_code":"gift_message_available","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"is_featured","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source","value":"28"},{"attribute_code":"hsncode","value":"85444299"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source_after_minprice","value":"-1"}]}],"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[],"page_size":2},"total_count":91}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "iterating"? Do you mean displaying the list in the UI (ng-repeat)?

Comment: yes but Ng-repeat is not working *ngFor is working for me. But I want to disply only Description in my UI .

Comment: do you mean you want to iterate data in "custom_attributes" inside items ?

Comment: Yes But not All the "value"'s only first "value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   // you can access your item here for example
  <h1>item.id</h1>
   // and you can loop again
  <div *ngFor="let temp of item.custom_attributes">
   <p> temp.attribute_code</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use *ngFor to iterate over an array of objects

Comment: I want "value" of the custom_attribute only not attribute_code. can you please suggest any thing for that.

Comment: Sorry for wrong information I wan First "value" in the custom_attribute.

Comment: you can access what you want from custom_attributes.
what you mean by first value ? (custom_attributes[0] ?)

Answer (score 0):

In your component.js,

```
 private myItems:any = [];

constructor(){
}

yourFunction(){
  let vm = this;
  items.forEach(function(val: any){
    val.custom_attributes.forEach(function(myAttrs: any){
      vm.myItems.push({
        "code": myAttrs.attribute_code,
        "description": myAttrs.value
      });
    });
  });
}
```

In your html file

```
<div *ngFor="let myItem of myItems">
  <p> Code: {{myItem.code}} </p>
  <p> Description : {{myItem.description}}
</div>
```